# How do I call a nested function from another function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have browsed this site looking for clues to help solve this problem but they were not specific enough to help solve it.

I have this login code that has a nested function that I need to call from another function which is outside the scope of the login script.

```
jstore.plugins.login = function(url, options) { 

    var login = jstore.plugins.login;
    var opts = $.extend(true, {}, jstore.plugins.login.defaults, options);
    var server = jstore.url2server({ url: url });

    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = jstore.uid();
        $this.append('<div class=\'jstore_widget jstore_login\' id=\'' + id + '\'></div>');
        var updated = function(server) {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            if(element) {
                var e = $(element);
        var loginDisplayed = $('.jstore_login_name', element).length == 1;
        if (server.loggedIn() === false && loginDisplayed) {
            return true;
        }
        e.html(login.getHTML(server, opts));
        if(server.loggedIn()) {
           e.click(function() {
              var server = jstore.getServer(url);
              if(server && server.loggedIn()) {
                 server.logout();
              }
        });
```

I need to call this part from somewhere else:

```
e.click(function() {
   var server = jstore.getServer(url);
   if(server && server.loggedIn()) {
      server.logout();}
```

Based on research from this site; I tried to call it directly by constructing the following line but it doesn't work:

```
jstore.plugins.login.updated().e.click();
```

I have little practical knowledge of jQuery. Keeping in mind that I am a novice; syntactically, what is the proper way to call a nested javascript function from a location outside the scope of its parent function?

Regards.

:::::::::::::UPDATE::::::::::::::

I was able to get this to work, many thanks to nuway for his excellent suggestion and others for their constructive criticism.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
jstore.plugins.login = function(url, options) { 

var login = jstore.plugins.login;
var opts = $.extend(true, {}, jstore.plugins.login.defaults, options);
var server = jstore.url2server({ url: url });

return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = jstore.uid();
    $this.append('<div class=\'jstore_widget jstore_login\' id=\'' + id + '\'></div>');

    window.onClick = function() {
        var server = jstore.getServer(url);
        if(server && server.loggedIn()) {
            server.logout();
            }
        };

    var updated = function(server) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if(element) {
            var e = $(element);
            var loginDisplayed = $('.jstore_login_name', element).length == 1;
        if (server.loggedIn() === false && loginDisplayed) {
            return true;
            }
            e.html(login.getHTML(server, opts));
        if(server.loggedIn()) {
           e.click(onClick);
        }
```

I just needed to globalize the onClick function with `window.onClick = ...` in order to call it from another function.

Comment: I see very few closing braces.

Comment: I only pasted a portion of the code. The closing braces are there just not shown.  Is necessary to post the entire block?

Comment: @user3674192 Can you ask a proper question, instead 'show me how its done'?

Comment: Sure.  Syntactically, what is the proper way to call a nested javascript function from a location outside the scope of its parent function?

Comment: You should reformat your code. If you want help you'd better make it easy for the readers.

Comment: Put the anonymous function in a variable in the outer scope so that you can call it by name from wherever you need. If you ware asking "how do I call a function which is out of scope," you can't; that's the whole point of scopes.

Comment: If it is outside the scope... then change the scope.  If you are not sure what scope is then read up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not put this block into its own function such as

```
var onClick = function() {
    var server = jstore.getServer(url);
    if(server && server.loggedIn()) {
          server.logout();
    }
}
```

and then you can just pass it in as such:

`e.click(onClick)`

and you can invoke it from somethere else by simply calling `onClick()`

Comment: Thank you, this seems like what I should do and I will try it.  Should `e.click(onClick)` be instantiated within `var updated`?